# jQuery Mobile Tabbar - Hide on Tab

Tags: jquery-mobile, tabbar

i m creat a JQuery Mobile Page with a Tabbar.
If i click on the content the Footer/Header disapears, how can i disbale that?

At the moment both Bars are fixed.

A quick sample would be perfect.

Comment: What version of JQM are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this with JQM 1.1.0

The first and easiest was is to set **data-tap-toggle="false"** in your fixed toolbar

`<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">`

The second way I like because it allows you to disable this in every page and every fixed toolbar. This way you won't drive yourself mad typing data-tap-toggle="false" over and over.

```
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
    $('[data-position=fixed]').fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle:false});
});
```

The following will disable the tap toggle in JQM 1.0.1

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role=page]','pageinit', function(){
    $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
});
```